# How to prevent asp.net ajax postback with JQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $('#bvft').addClass("bvft");

        $('#new').live('click', function() {
            $('#bvft').removeClass("bvft");
            $('#bvft').show("slow");
        });

        $('.ddlFrTime').change(function() {
            var vFTime = $('.ddlFrTime').val();

            if (vFTime != "") {
                $('#bvft').removeClass("bvft");
                $('#bvft').show("slow");
            }
            else { alert("sorry"); }
        }); 
    }        
</script>
```

In $('#bvft'), I have one dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFrTime" runat="server" Width="250px" CssClass="ddlFrTime" AutoPostBack="true"
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFrTime_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

$(#bvft) is div id.
$('#new') is button id.
When page load, I want to disable. It works perfect.
When I click the button, $(#bvft) div will show.
But the problem is (in div, I have dropdownlist) when I select dropdownlist, the postback will work. At this time div is automatically hide back.
How to prevent for this. Actually I used function pageLoad() to prevent postback.
But it's not working.

Comment: does `return false` work? I know it stops the href action of a link. Worth a try I guess

Comment: do u mean 'return false' for button? if you mean like this... button is okay no problem... the problem is dropdownlist postback. thanks for reply...

Comment: Sorry, inside the jQuery event for change()

Comment: @PostMan I changed like this
'$('.ddlFrTime').change(function() {
                var vFTime = $('.ddlFrTime').val();

                if (vFTime != "") {
                    $('#bvft').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#bvft').show("slow");
                }
                return false;
            }); '

But not okay :(

Answer (score 2):

Set autopostback to false for the dropdownbox

Comment: if i set autopostback to false, how to do for dropdownlist selectedIndexChanged?

Comment: Your page has to post if you want to fire that event.

Comment: @CMMaung what behavior you want in your selectedIndexChanged event? Does it have to be done in server side? if not, maybe you can do it with js

Answer (score -1):

Now I got an answer...
I put some code after function pageLoad()... like this

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (!args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            $('#bvft').slideUp('slow');
        }
        else {
            $('#bvft').slideDown('slow');
        }
    }
```

It will work pretty... no problem for postback...

Comment: @iamserious which part you are not clear? you need to use that one 
if (!args.get_isPartialLoad())